# \n can't be posted to a MYSQL server

Tags: mysql, json, utf-8

I am trying to get, post and put JSON data to a MYSQL server (docker container) that uses utf8 as the charset. Within this JSON data are strings that should contain "\n". When the data is applied in my application these "\n" are causing linebreaks which **is what I want**.

But when I try to insert this into my database it throws an error: "ERROR 3140 (22032) at line x: "Invalid JSON text: "Invalid encoding in string.".

Solutions I found suggested adding additional backslashes (" '\' \n"). While this works for inserting, it doesn't allow for the linebreaks I wanted in my application. Is there some way around without changing the application ?

SQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, json) VALUES (1,'{"data": "name: ab \n cost: 5 $ | time: 1 s"}')
```

Comment: Can your application render HTML? If so, change the \n to <br>

Comment: If MySQL is triggering a JSON error that means that you have a JSON column and you've feeding it with invalid JSON. Trying to mess with your broken data is unlikely to make things better. Can you please edit the question and provide some actual information?

Comment: `\n` is a escape sequence in PHP, JavaScript, MySQL, JSON and many other languages. You're possibly sending an actual carriage return rather than a backslash followed by letter n.

Comment: The part that renders the data sadly doesn't understand HTML syntax. <br> did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (id, json) VALUES (1,'{"data": "name: ab \n cost: 5 $ | time: 1 s"}')
```

`\n` is a escape sequence in SQL so you're sending an actual carriage return character rather than a backslash followed by letter n, which is what JSON mandates. It's more obvious with this other query:

```
mysql> select '{"data": "name: ab \n cost: 5 $ | time: 1 s"}' as test;
+----------------------------------------------+
| test                                         |
+----------------------------------------------+
| {"data": "name: ab
 cost: 5 $ | time: 1 s"} |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To insert a literal `\` in MySQL you need to escape with another `\`:

```
mysql> select 'one\\ntwo' as test;
+----------+
| test     |
+----------+
| one\ntwo |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please note this is only an issue when you type literal strings in your code. It won't affect data coming from other sources (e.g. HTML forms or databases) unless you fail to process it somewhere (e.g. by injecting it in raw SQL rather than using prepared statements).

Comment: This helped me understand what was going on. When loading in the data from my dump \n caused issues. This answer allows me to load it correctly from the dump. However I still have the issue that if I want to post from the app to database that I need to modify the data. I guess mysql doesn't provide a solution and I have to do that myself.

Comment: Typically, your query would look like `INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (?)` and you'd pass your JSON as parameter, thus no escaping is required.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. How do I pass my JSON data as a parameter and how would it avoid my problem ?

Comment: You say the problem remains in some app. That app is written in some programming language with some database library. Launch the documentation for that library and search for "prepared statements". Prepared statements avoid escaping problems because they are an alternative to escaping that solve the problem without the need of escaping.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me fix the issue. Maybe you could edit your answer to include this comment.